# Hi, I am trying to apply covariance risk budget constraints in a Markowitz mean variance model. I am not able to use the solver 'solveRdonlp2'

Tags: optimization, portfolio

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘Rdonlp2’

Where can I download the package

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Install rtools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html)
2. `install.packages("Rdonlp2", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`